# Add additional node to destination based on source existence

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

Is there any way to add an additional node to destination based on source field existence using normal BizTalk functoids or xslt should be used?

For example : 
If source field exists then add new additional node to destination 
Otherwise don’t add new node to destination .
I want to know whether this can be achieved with BizTalk functoids or xslt should be used .

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in a standard map.

1. Have the element defined in your destination schema with it's Min Occurs set to 0
2. Use one of the logical functoids e.g. Logical Existence that you link from the source element to the destination
3. And also a link directly between the source element and the destination element.

You can also use other logical funtoids like Logical String or Logical Numberic if the field may exist but not contain a value and you then don't want the destination element.